# Search for string in one sheet and update cell in another sheet

Tags: regex, excel, vba

My excel workbook has a "Main" tab/sheet which looks like this

### Name   | Last-Payment | Ontime/Late |

### Andy   | December     |  Late       |

### Dick    | January      |  On-time   |

### Nathan  | February     |   Late     |

### Jimmy   | September    |   Late     |

And each Name has a separate Sheet/Tab with a table:

### Month  |  Paid

### December | Yes

### Jan      | Yes

### Feb      | No

### Mar      | No

When a person makes a payment for a certain month, the "Paid" column is updated with a "Yes"

I am looking for a way to update the main sheet for the appropriate person when the paid month for that person is updated.
For example:
When Andy makes a payment for the month of January,the appropriate month  for Andy is entered as "Yes". Now, this column is read and I would look for the recent paid month and the month is compared with the current month and the Late/On-time column in the main sheet is updated.

I would like to know if writing a VBA script would accomplish this or some kind of Lookup (Vlookup, hlookup etc) would.

I am not looking for any code.
Suggestions on how I should approach the problem is highly appreciated.

Sincere apologies for the table format.

Thank you

Comment: Yes It's possible to do that with VBA and I think also with basic excel functionallity. In table 1 which month is displayed? the last paid month of the  customer?

Comment: yes. The last paid month.